# serialize property as attribute of another property

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, types, cdata

I need to serialize an object and the xml should be formatted as:

```
<ATTRIBUTES>
     <ATTRIBUTE type="Colour"><![CDATA["Black"]]></ATTRIBUTE>
     <ATTRIBUTE type="Size"><![CDATA["One Size"]]></ATTRIBUTE>
</ATTRIBUTES>
```

I can get CDATA by using the following but i cant figure out how to put 'type' in there too:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlArrayItem("ATTRIBUTE")]
    public XmlCDataSection[] ATTRIBUTES { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I modified the title since "prefix" would be misleading. What you're looking for is adding a "type" attribute to your "ATTRIBUTE" element.

Comment: Do you know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: I have now sorted, in case anyone else has the same problem or can enhance what i have done: